# iPhone: UILabel text does not fit the way i want

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UILabel with some text on it, what I want is if the text with the given font does not fit to the label, I want it to be **first** linebreaked to a second line, and if still does not fit **then** it should automatically adjust those 2 lines to a smaller font.

I experienced with the IB changing the settings of linebreaks and number of rows, but couldn't get what I want.

Any recommendadtions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge UILabel does not support auto adjusting the font when there is more than one line.

The only way I know of it to iteratively calculate a fitting font size and then to set the appropriate font manually.

Comment: how can i only make 2 lines if not fit? but text should center itself vertically in the UILabel

Comment: `setNumberOfLines:2` This should center the text vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `sizeWithFont:` method is a solution for you:
[– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:)
This calculates the width / height of a `NSString` with the appropriate font / settings